# bundler incorrectly trying to install "development" and "test" group gems in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, bundler, unicorn

I have a small web app, which uses a bunch of gems. Some of them are only used for `test` and `development` environments. Now, when I try to start unicorn on the production server using the following command, it fails.

```
unicorn_rails -E production -D -c config/unicorn.rb
```

The error I see in the log files is:

```
Refreshing Gem list
Could not find gem 'spork (>= 0.9.0.rc2, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Try running `bundle install`.
```

I've pasted my gemfile below:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.1'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'mongoid', '>= 2.0.0.beta.19'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'haml', '>= 3.0.0'
gem 'bson'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'bluecloth'

group :production do
  gem 'capistrano'
end

group :development do
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'hpricot', '0.8.2'
  gem 'ruby_parser', '2.0.5'
  gem 'less'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.0.1'
end

group :development,:test do
  gem 'spork', '>=0.9.0.rc2'
  gem 'mongoid-rspec'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'test_notifier'
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
  gem 'launchy' 
end
```

Bundler is supposed to detect the right environment and ignore the other gems, right? Right now, I am deleting all the lines which are not in the default group on the server to get this working, but that's an ugly hack.

Comment: Capistrano in production doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found the fix for this issue. All I had to do was run `bundle install --without development test` before starting the server. This adds a `.bundle/config` file in the rails root with the line `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: test:development` . Now whenever you run `bundle install` or start the server it'll ignore those groups.

[From the documentation](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#OPTIONS)

> The Bundler CLI allows you to specify
>   a list of groups whose gems bundle
>   install should not install with the
>   --without option. To specify multiple groups to ignore, specify a list of
>   groups separated by spaces.
>
> bundle install --without test bundle
>   install --without development test
>   After running bundle install --without
>   test, bundler will remember that you
>   excluded the test group in the last
>   installation. The next time you run
>   bundle install, without any --without
>   option, bundler will recall it.
>
> Also, calling Bundler.setup with no
>   parameters, or calling require
>   "bundler/setup" will setup all groups
>   except for the ones you excluded via
>   --without (since they are obviously not available).

Comment: Thank you! Was looking for the syntax for the config file :)

BUNDLE_WITHOUT: test:development

Comment: I think this is just bad design.  Why not ignore anything non-dev by default?  You shouldn't have to group in the gemfile and exclude through the command line.  It should default to the dev environment and then you include either production or test.  Otherwise it's a lot of redundancy and headaches during development.

Comment: @PhillipKregg Bundler has no concept of a "dev environment" as distinct from gem groups. Rails does, but Bundler shouldn't couple its installation behavior to the internals of another gem (and not every project uses Rails).

Comment: Today I learned.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was installing gems from jenkins env. So i had to set my own bundle_without variable in capistrano.

Gemfile

```
group :test, :development, :jenkins do  
  gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'  
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

deploy.rb

```
set :bundle_without, [:development, :test, :jenkins]
```

Answer (score -2):

You haven't defined a production group =)

Comment: Dunno, you could try ;p See if it still asks the spork gem.

Comment: Don't know that much about testing unfortunately (o.O)

Comment: just tried it with a production group containing capistrano, still throws the same error :(

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct environment in the spec_helper? Check this: http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:spork

Comment: actually I just removed the :test and the ":development, :test" groups (I didn't remove the :development group). Now it complains about 'hpricot'

Comment: Well you do need hpricot, ruby_parser and less in your production environment. So you also need to add those to the production group.

Comment: Isn't production group supposed to have the gems that are needed in `production` rather than the gems which should be not loaded?

Comment: Indeed. What purpose does 'hpricot' have in your app?

Comment: it's used to convert `devise` erb views to haml