# scp deployments in rails3 using bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Ok, this thorny issue has come up again and we are still having a difficult time finding a solution.

## Problem

We have a Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

When deploying to production Passenger blows up because it can't find gem 'debugger'.

## Constraints

- ops will not install 'debugger' into prod
- we can't run any shell commands after deployment, such as `bundle install` or `bundle --without development`
- we cannot run `bundle --without development` locally and copy the Gemfile.lock or .bundle/* dir (as has been [suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142126/can-bundler-be-used-in-rsync-deployments)) because our development machine is a different architecture than our prod machines.
- the prod machines are isolated from http://rubygems.org.  The *only* way gems are installed/updated on prod machines is by requesting ops to manually `gem install`.
- the gems for all apps are shared on the prod machines (no rvm, etc.)
- we do have a rake task that runs after deploy

## Our Current Solutions

- check out the Gemfile and comment out development groups before releasing to prod.  uncomment later.  repeat depending on position in the release cycle. (error prone)

## Possible Solutions I Can Think Of

- keep two versions of the Gemfile (i.e. Gemfile.dev Gemfile.prod) and swap/cp them to Gemfile with a rake task.

Comment: if you were on a different runtime, you could use the ```:platforms``` keyword...

Comment: it might be possible to play around with the ```:path``` option to trick bundler and just ignore it in production and use the actual gem in development.